# proving a wiki statement about uniform convergence and supremum

Tags: real-analysis

[This wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) says that a sequence $f_n$ is uniformally convergenct to  $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $||f_n - f||_{\sup} \to 0$. I am trying to prove this statement.

For the forward implication, we have that $f_n \to f$ uniformaly, so we have that $|f_n - f| < \epsilon$. Now, it seems as though the obvious option here is to simply take the supremum of this to get the result if we choose $N$ which gives us $|f_n - f| < \epsilon$. How would I do this step by step, I mean - it seems wrong to just take the supremum of everything as this doesn't use the fact that $f_n$ is uniformaly convergent to $f$

I have yet to try the backwards implication.

Answer (score 1):

It's just another way to state the definition :

This is your base definition

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, \forall n > N, \forall x, \quad |f_n(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon$$

This is what means $\|f_n-f\|_{\sup} \to 0$ :

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, \forall n > N, \quad  \|f_n-f\|_{\sup} < \epsilon$$

And now replace $\|f_n-f\|_{\sup}$ by it's definition :

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, \forall n > N, \quad  \sup_{x} |f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$$

And it's the same thing that

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, \forall n > N, \forall x, \quad |f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$$